# Groupby multiple columns and draw boxplot in Python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

Given a dataset `df` as follows:

```
   variable_name       date  pred_value  real_value
0         import  2022/3/31     2721.80     2736.20
1         import  2022/3/31     2721.80     2736.20
2         import  2022/3/31     2705.50     2736.20
3         import  2022/3/31     2500.00     2736.20
4         import  2022/3/31     2900.05     2736.20
5         import  2022/4/30     2795.66     2759.98
6         import  2022/4/30     2694.45     2759.98
7         import  2022/4/30     2855.36     2759.98
8         import  2022/4/30     2300.00     2759.98
9            GDP  2022/3/31        1.13        1.10
10           GDP  2022/3/31        1.13        1.10
11           GDP  2022/3/31        1.17        1.10
12           GDP  2022/3/31        0.91        1.10
13           GDP  2022/4/30        1.29        1.30
14           GDP  2022/4/30        1.29        1.30
15           GDP  2022/4/30        1.28        1.30
16           GDP  2022/4/30        1.50        1.30
```

Code:

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
dfm = df.melt(id_vars=['variable_name', 'date'])

p = sns.relplot(kind='scatter', data=dfm, x='date', y='value', row='variable_name', height=4, 
                aspect=2.5, hue='variable',
                palette=['tab:blue', 'tab:red'], 
                alpha=0.5,
                facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': True})
p.set_xticklabels(rotation=30)
# p.xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator())
# p.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))
```

Out:

[image]

For the plot above, instead of scatter plot, if I wanna to draw the blue color scatters with **boxplot**. How could I do that? Thanks.

Please note the purpose of doing so it to use the probability distribution of `pred_value` to estimate the `real_value`.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I understand what you want to plot, but if you want a box plot with density distribution you can try using the `seaborn` library (it works very well with `pandas` dataframes, as an example: you can use the `distplot()` function from that library.
You can find more plot types and examples [Here.](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this link, it's helpful.